# From the `environment` to a `list`

Tags: r, list, environment

I have a set of datasets that end with `.fin`. I would like to create a list and merge them using

```
ls(pattern = ".fin")
"A.fin" "B.fin" "C.fin" "D.fin" "E.fin" "F.fin" "G.fin" "H.fin" "I.fin"
"J.fin" "K.fin" "L.fin" "M.fin" "N.fin"
```

I would like to go from the line and code above to the line below beginning with `list`, like `list(ls(pattern = ".fin"))`; however this only returns a vector in a list of the data set names. I have also tried using `list(get(ls(pattern = ".fin"))` and `list(eval(parse(text = ls(pattern = .fin))))` with no avail.

```
list(ls(pattern = ".fin")) ### <- REPLACE THIS SOMEHOW  %>%
Reduce(function(dtf1,dtf2) full_join(dtf1,dtf2,by="i"), .)
```

Comment: `sapply(ls(pattern = ".fin"), FUN = get)` perhaps?

Comment: Worked like a charm. I didn't even consider using `apply`.

Comment: Some functions are not vectorized so you have to "use the loop" one way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mget`:

```
mget(ls(pattern = ".fin"))
```

---

```
A.fin <- c(1,2,3)
B.fin <- c(4,5,6)

mget(ls(pattern = ".fin"))
#$A.fin
#[1] 1 2 3

#$B.fin
#[1] 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

`get` is not vectorized so you should "loop" over whatever `ls()` is returning. You can do that either

```
sapply(ls(pattern = ".fin"), FUN = get)
```

or the long way

```
xy <- ls(pattern = ".fin")
mylist <- vector("list", length(xy))

for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  mylist[[i]] <- get(xy[i])
}
```

or use `mget(ls(pattern = ".fin"))`.